# Bashrc not running on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: command-line, 20.04, virtualbox, bashrc

.bashrc is not running when i open terminal on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Moreover, when i use source to run it, it throws and error:

`` /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1512: parse error near `|' ``

And the shell name gets messed:

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$`

I am running Ubuntu on virtualbox btw. Just installed it.

Comment: Are you sure that you are sourcing the file *into bash* - rather than another shell (`zsh` for example)?

Comment: @steeldriver i was sourcing into zsh. that solved the problem. i didnt know there were other shells in ubuntu, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using zsh instead of bash. That is what was causing the problem.

I had to modify .zshrc instead of .bashrc.